# Joining in the row with max value via a jointable

Tags: mysql, join

Usually when I need to join the row with some max value from another column I do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON (a.aid = b.aid)
LEFT JOIN b nullb ON (a.aid = nullb.aid AND nullb.value > b.value)
WHERE nullb.bid IS NULL;
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficent way but it is a solution without subqueries which i avoid whenever possible.

Today I needed to join in the max value from another table that joins in via a jointable and could not figure out a way to do it.

I tried something like this: (which failed miserably)

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN atob ON (a.aid = atob.aid)
INNER JOIN b ON (atob.bid = b.bid)
LEFT JOIN atob nullatob ON (a.aid = nullatob.aid)
LEFT JOIN b nullb ON (nullatob.bid = nullb.bid AND nullb.value > b.value)
WHERE nullb.bid IS NULL;
```

I set up an sqlfiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86f18/6 with the problem set up.

Anyone got a clever way to join in the max value from another table via a jointable without using subqueries or is that pretty much impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your goal but:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86f18/13

```
SELECT A.*, b.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN AtoB 
ON (A.Aid = AtoB.Aid)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT B.* 
  FROM B
  LEFT JOIN b nullB 
  ON (B.Bid = nullB.Bid AND nullB.bdate > B.Bdate)
  WHERE nullB.Bid IS NULL
  ) b
ON AtoB.Bid = b.Bid
```